# Combinations problem for a objects larger than the sample with a twist - people and elavators

Tags: combinatorics

There are 300 people in a building. There are 5 elevators in the building and there are maximum 15 people to an elevator.

How many combinations are there of people in the lifts?

The order of the elevators matter, but not the order in which the people enter them. Say I have a set of just 5 people, A, B, C, D and E and I label the elevators 1,2,3,4,5 - then these should be 2 separate options:

```
A1, B2, C3, D4, E5
A5, B4, C3, D2, E1
```

Initially I tried:
   (300 chose 15)*(285 chose 15)*(270 chose 15)*(260 chose 15)*(245 chose 15)
But this only takes into account if the lifts are full. So I came up with this idea:

```
  (300 chose 15)*(285 chose 15)*(270 chose 15)*(260 chose 15)*(245 chose 15)
+ (300 chose 15)*(285 chose 15)*(270 chose 15)*(260 chose 15)*(245 chose 14)
+ (300 chose 15)*(285 chose 15)*(270 chose 15)*(260 chose 15)*(245 chose 13) ...
```

but this seems very inelegant and there would be 15^5 rows in this equation.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Does the order of elevators matter? Does the order of people matter? This problem is not well-defined.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, i have edited the original question

Comment: You can simplify the notation slightly by using multinomial coefficients instead of products of binomial coefficients such as $\binom{300}{15,15,15,15,15,225}$, but otherwise I do not see an elegant way to simplify the result further.  Your attempt does appear to be correct even if too tedious to actually calculate.

Comment: I'm a little unclear what the problem asks for.  Perhaps you want to enumerate all the possible outcomes, where the outcome is determined by the subset of 300 people in the building in each of five elevators.  Perhaps some elevators are empty at a given point in time, but an elevator can hold at most 15 (distinguishable) people, and the contents of two distinct elevators are disjoints sets of people.  If I wanted to count the outcomes, I'd start with the size of all the people in the elevators and construct the solutions using just a subset of that size (partitioned by the five elevators).

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.